# WebView2 change Save as PDF default filename

Tags: wpf, webview2

I am using WebView2 control as a PDF viewer in my WPF application. I am creating pdf with random names on the disk and showing them to the user depending on selection from a list view.

The issue is, the user can press the Save as pdf button within the PDF viewer and this opens the Save file dialog which has the randomly generated name as a default. Is there a way to change the default filename of the Save as PDF dialog without changing the original filename of the pdf file?

Comment: What WebView2 API are you using? CoreWebView2.PrintToPdfAsync prints the current document to a PDF and the first parameter is the full path name https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.printtopdfasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1823.32

Comment: @DavidRisney This is true, although the question was about the built-in Save as pdf button of the WebView2 control itself. I found out later that you can hide this button and then moved functionality on another button that I had more control over. The feature I originally asked about seems not to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the default file name is based on the HTML Title of the current document. Change or add an HTML Title tag to set the default file name before calling `webView.CoreWebView2.ShowPrintUI()`.